# Checking if a value exists in sqlite db with Go

Tags: sql, sqlite, go

I'm writing code to manage users in a sqlite database with Go.

I'm trying to check if a username is taken, but my code is ugly.

My table looks like:

```
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    username TEXT UNIQUE,
    password TEXT
```

And I check if a username is taken with:

```
func UserExists(db * sql.DB, username string) bool {
    sqlStmt := `SELECT username FROM userinfo WHERE username = ?`
    count := 0
    rows, err := db.Query(sqlStmt, username)
    Check(err)
    for rows.Next() {  // Can I just check if rows is non-zero somehow?
        count++
    }
    return len(rows) != 0
}
```

Is there a better query I could use that would tell me if the username value exists in the table in a more staight forward way? Or is there a nicer way to check if `rows` is non-zero?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use [`QueryRow`](https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#DB.QueryRow) to query at most one row. If the query doesn't return any row, it returns `sql.ErrNoRows`.

```
func UserExists(db * sql.DB, username string) bool {
    sqlStmt := `SELECT username FROM userinfo WHERE username = ?`
    err := db.QueryRow(sqlStmt, username).Scan(&username)
    if err != nil {
        if err != sql.ErrNoRows {
            // a real error happened! you should change your function return
            // to "(bool, error)" and return "false, err" here
            log.Print(err)
        }

        return false
    }

    return true
}
```

Comment: Not sure why this is marked as the correct answer. This code does not work.

Comment: Thanks for noticing it! Why did I post such code? :o

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a bit old, but I don't see any clean answers here. Notice below the if rows.Next() statement which will return a boolean if there are any rows or not:

```
package main

import (
    "database/sql"
    _ "github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3"
    "log"
)

func main() {
    exists, _ := SelectDBRowExists(`SELECT * FROM GEO_VELOCITY_EVENTS WHERE USERNAME='bob'`)
    log.Println(exists)
}

func SelectDBRowExists(query string) (bool, error) {

    DbConn, err := sql.Open("sqlite3", "/path/to/your/sql.sqlite3")
    if err != nil {
        return false, err
    }
    defer DbConn.Close()
    err = DbConn.Ping()

    if err != nil {
        return false, err
    }

    rows, err := DbConn.Query(query)

    if rows.Next() {
        return true, nil
    } else {
        return false, nil
    }

    defer rows.Close()

    return false, nil
}
```

Comment: You return before calling `defer rows.Close()`. `rows` will leak.

Answer (score 1):

as long as you are only concerned about the existence of one single information in the Database. I found that this method is quite simpler and efficient.

```
func emailExists(email string) bool {
    row := db.QueryRow("select user_email from users where user_email= ?", email)
    checkErr(err)
    temp := ""
    row.Scan(&temp)
    if temp != "" {
        return true
    }
    return false
}
```

if u noticed am only getting a single row.
the result of my Query gets scanned in a temp Variable.

then I check whether the temp Variable is empty or not.

if it is not empty, true is returned.

Answer (score 0):

i think we can use above function to check that condition is already exist at database.

```
if helper.UserExists(db, username) {
    return username, errors.New("data already exist")
}
```

because that function returned bool that means if that function is called return will return by default is true.
i hope this usefull.